# DeleteFile throwing IsolatedStorageFileException within a ContextMenu

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstoragefile

Writing a WP7.1 (Mango) app in Silverlight for Windows Phone (XAML / C#). I have an exception that I just cannot shake. I have a ListBox displaying an `ObservableCollection<string>` which displays the file names of XML files from `IsolatedStorage`. The Listbox control also contains a `ContextMenu` from the Windows Phone Toolkit. I use it to delete items from my ListBox, and from disk.

The `ContextMenu` and my delete method works fine normally... But if, whilst on the same page without navigating away, I create a new file (let's call it File1) then create another file (File2), if I then attempt to delete File1, the `IsolateStorageFile.DeleteFile` method throws an exception stating "An error occurred while accessing IsolatedStorage" with an inner message of null. HOWEVER, if I create File1, then File2. Then delete File2 then File1, it works just fine! ARGH!

If I leave the Page or restart the app again, I can delete the file no problems.

I've stripped back the code to hopefully make it a bit easier to read.

UI Binding Collection field in the code behind.

```
    ObservableCollection<string> Subjects;
```

Click event calls the write method.

```
    private void Button_Click_AddNewSubject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TryWriteNewSubject(NewSubjectNameTextBox.Text))
        {
            ... Manipulate UI
        }
    }
```

Method to Add file to IsoStore and Subjects collection. Returns a bool for conditional UI manipulation.

```
    private bool TryWriteNewSubject(string subjectName)
    {
            ... file name error checking 

                using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    store.OpenFile(subjectName + ".xml", FileMode.CreateNew);
                    store.Dispose();
                }
                Subjects.Add(subjectName);
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

The ContextMenu click event calls the delete file method

```
    private void ContextMenuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string subjectName = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as string;
        DeleteFile(subjectName);
    }
```

And my delete method

```
    private void DeleteFile(string subjectName)
    {
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                string fileName = subjectName + ".xml";
                store.DeleteFile(fileName);
                Subjects.Remove(subjectName);
            }
    }
```

The code is straight forward, I just don't know what I'm missing. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `IsolatedStorageFileStream` from [`OpenFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190070%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). You need to dispose it before another operation can manipulate it.

Btw, a using statement calls dispose for you, so there's no need to call dispose at the end of a `using` statement.

Comment: GAH! I knew it was something simple. Thanks so much!

I'm aware the using statement is meant to dispose for you, but I was running out of ideas and I put that in my code before pasting it to SO :P

Comment: :-) We all do some crazy stuff from time to time when things don't work as expected. Good luck with your application